# Dbcontext not able to migrate because schema does not exist?

Tags: postgresql, entity-framework, entity-framework-core, dbcontext, npgsql

I am currently writing some integrations test which affect the database just in a different schema.

I am following this guide
https://www.thinktecture.com/en/entity-framework-core/isolation-of-integration-tests-in-2-1/

My problem is with this abstract class used for creating DbContext?

```
public abstract class IntegrationTestsBase<T> : IDisposable
  where T : DbContext
{
  private readonly string _schema;
  private readonly string _historyTableName;
  private readonly DbContextOptions<T> _options;

  protected T DbContext { get; }

  protected IntegrationTestsBase()
  {
    _schema = Guid.NewGuid().ToString("N");
    _historyTableName = "__EFMigrationsHistory";

    _options = CreateOptions();
    DbContext = CreateContext();
    DbContext.Database.Migrate();
  }

  protected abstract T CreateContext(DbContextOptions<T> options, 
                                     IDbContextSchema schema);

  protected T CreateContext()
  {
    return CreateContext(_options, new DbContextSchema(_schema));
  }

  private DbContextOptions<T> CreateOptions()
  {
    return new DbContextOptionsBuilder<T>()
        .UseNpgsql($"Server=(local);Database=Demo;...", 
                builder => builder.MigrationsHistoryTable(_historyTableName, _schema))
        .ReplaceService<IMigrationsAssembly, DbSchemaAwareMigrationAssembly>()
        .ReplaceService<IModelCacheKeyFactory, DbSchemaAwareModelCacheKeyFactory>()
        .Options;
  }

  public void Dispose()
  {
    DbContext.GetService<IMigrator>().Migrate("0");
    DbContext.Database.ExecuteSqlCommand(
           (string)$"DROP TABLE [{_schema}].[{_historyTableName}]");
    DbContext.Database.ExecuteSqlCommand((string)$"DROP SCHEMA [{_schema}]");

    DbContext?.Dispose();
  }
}
```

DbContext is being created, but once the migrations is being called  i get an error stating that the schema, does not exist?

which I am not sure why because i in my ensure the in my configuration

```
public class SchemaContext : DbContext, IDbContextSchema
{
    public virtual DbSet<Schema>? SchemaModel { get; set; }

    public SchemaContext()
    {
    }

    public SchemaContext(DbContextOptions<SchemaContext> options, IDbContextSchema schema = null)
        : base(options)
    {
        Schema = schema.Schema;
    }

    protected override void OnModelCreating(ModelBuilder modelBuilder)
    {
        modelBuilder.HasDefaultSchema(Schema);
        //base.OnModelCreating(modelBuilder);
        modelBuilder.ApplyConfigurationsFromAssembly(Assembly.GetExecutingAssembly());
    }

    public string Schema { get; }
}
```

I would assume that `modelBuilder.HasDefaultSchema(Schema);` would have created the schema?

which does not seem to be case,  hence migration fails? what am I missing? why is the schema not being created in the actual database?

Comment: In my demos I'm using SQL Server and EF Core for SQL Server is creating the schema automatically when the table `__EFMigrationsHistory` is created. Postgres might behave differently.
[Real code on Azure DevOps](https://dev.azure.com/pawelgerr/_git/Thinktecture.EntityFrameworkCore?path=%2Fsrc%2FThinktecture.EntityFrameworkCore.SqlServer.Testing%2FEntityFrameworkCore%2FTesting%2FSqlServerDbContextIntegrationTests.cs). ([Docs](https://dev.azure.com/pawelgerr/Thinktecture.EntityFrameworkCore/_wiki/wikis/Thinktecture.EntityFrameworkCore.wiki/12/Base-class-for-isolation-of-tests))

Answer (score 0):

In your could you are configure Context with method - UseSqlServer which is used only for MS SQL, you have to use Npgsql.EntityFrameworkCore.PostgreSql package and configure you context with UseNpgsql extension method:

```
.UseNpgsql("Host=localhost;Port=5432;Database=my_db;Username=postgres;Password=password");
```

Comment: Incorrect connection string -  but yes I am using npgsql

Comment: Server=(local);Database=Demo; it looks like you are connecting to ms sql, you could use ConnectionStringBuilder (https://learn.microsoft.com/ru-ru/dotnet/api/system.data.common.dbconnectionstringbuilder?view=netcore-3.1) to assemble conn str. And One more note, as I remember postgres is not working with uppercase db name, so you should use "demo" instead of "Demo"

Comment: I am connecting to the correct database, the string itself is not incorrect.. is the fact that I try to create a schema that is not possible.